# Remove leading zeros in ggplot2 + scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a journal submission, I've been told that my figures can't have leading zeros. For example, take this plot:

```
df <- data.frame(x = -10:10, y = (-10:10)/10)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

The y-axis has the labels

```
-1.0  -0.5   0.0   0.5   1.0
```

I need to produce these labels:

```
-1.0   -.5   0      .5    1.0
```

I imagine I'll have to use `format_format()` from the scales package, but I haven't seen anything in the various documentation for `format`, `formatC` and `sprintf` that would produce the necessary labels.

Comment: Seems more consistent where 0 has a decimal point `-1.0   -.5   .0      .5    1.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a GitHub package, [numform](https://github.com/trinker/numform) that can do this (I added control over zeros to the `f_num` function based on this question):

```
library(devtools)
library(ggplot2)
install_github('trinker/numform')

df <- data.frame(x = -10:10, y = (-10:10)/10)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = numform::ff_num(zero = 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own function:

```
no_zero <- function(x) {
  y <- sprintf('%.1f',x)
  y[x > 0 & x < 1] <- sprintf('.%s',x[x > 0 & x < 1]*10)
  y[x == 0] <- '0'
  y[x > -1 & x < 0] <- sprintf('-.%s',x[x > -1 & x < 0]*-10)
  y
}
```

and then plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = no_zero)
```

which gives the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
geom_point()+
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c("-1.0" = -1, "-.5"= -0.5, "0" = 0, ".5" = 0.5, "1.0" = 1))
```

[image: plot with desired y axis labels]

Unfortunately this requires specifying the format manually for each plot; I don't know off the top of my head how to do the formatting automatically.